# How to automaticily rename file sort by date created on WIndows using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, windows-server-2012-r2

**My OS is Windows**

My file is:

```
FILENAME DATECREATED
Jack.txt 3 AM
John.txt 4 AM
Mary.txt 5 AM
Paul.txt 1 AM
```

So how to automaticily rename files in bulk sort by date created with this pattern:

Expected result:

```
FILENAME    DATECREATED
1. Paul.txt 1 AM
2. Jack.txt 3 AM
3. John.txt 4 AM
4. Mary.txt 5 AM
```

- Paul.txt is changed to "1. Paul.txt" because this file create first
  (at 1 AM).
- Mary.txt is changed to "4. Mary.txt" because this file
  create last (at 5 AM)

I heard there are some scripting to this issue, but I'm not sure too

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, get the files in the correct order ( `/od` sorts by date/time, `/a-d` excludes foldernames, `/b` does list only the filenames. See `dir /?` for details).
Then number them (by piping them to `findstr /N`. See `findstr /?` for details).
Then use a `for /f` loop to dissect the output into the number and filename and reassemble them to your needs (see `for /?` for details)

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /od /a-d /b ^|findstr /N "^"') do ECHO ren "%%b" "%%a. %%b"
```

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `ren` command by just echoing it. When the output satisfies you, just remove the `ECHO`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried and it work
BUT... the result is reverse, the oldest is last instead of first
Paul.txt is changed to "4. Paul.txt" instead of "1. Paul.txt"
Luckily you tell me to see dir/? for details so I run dir/? and found the answer
dir /o-d is should be only dir /od
But thank you for nice answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Stephan for the enlightment

This is the batch script to solve this issue,

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /od /a-d /b ^|findstr /N "^"') do ren "%%b" "%%a. %%b"
```